# How am I able to call a method that returns a value from a different method?

Tags: java

I am trying to call a method that has a value that comes from a different method but modified. Here is the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Test{



    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        int num;

    System.out.println("Please enter an integer");
    num = in.nextInt();

    System.out.println(Multiply(num));
    System.out.println(Multiply2(x));

    }

    public static int Multiply(int num){
        int x = num*2;
        return x;
    }

    public static int Multiply2(int x){
        int val = x*2;
        return val;
    }

}
```

I know I have to declare x inside of main but then I have to initialize it but I want the value of x to equal to the one that equals to the Multiply2 method which multiplies the num from the method, Multiply, by 2. x would be equal to num multiplied by 2; How am I able to do this?

Comment: `int x = Multiply(num);`???  If that doesn't work, then I don't understand the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your methods are exactly the **same**

The name of the variable doesn't matter. Wheter its called x or val, it makes no difference.

With that in mind, if you want `x` to be the value returned from your `Multiply` function, just store that in a variable and use it later. For instance,

```
int someValue = Multiply(num);
System.out.println(someValue);
System.out.println(Multiply2(someValue));
```

PS: By convention, we don't capitalize methods names. So they should be `multiply` and `multiply2`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I got it now.

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num;

        System.out.println("Please enter an integer");
        num = in.nextInt();

        System.out.println(Multiply(num));
        System.out.println(Multiply2(Multiply(num)));
    }

    public static int Multiply(int num) {
        int x = num * 2;
        return x;
    }

    public static int Multiply2(int x) {
        int val = x * 2;
        return val;
    }
}
```